# Setting MongoDb log verbosity level to minimize the logs

Tags: mongodb, logging, mongodb-replica-set, verbosity

I have setup 3 replicas on mongodb. I am facing a lot of mongoDb logs in the log file of mongodb, and I want to  minimize the logs to show only errors, warning and critical logs but not for connection and access. to which verbosity level I should have to set the logs?

My current setting for logs in config file:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /data/log/mongodb/mongod.log
  component:
      accessControl:
         verbosity: 1
      command:
         verbosity: 1
      # COMMENT some component verbosity settings omitted for brevity
      replication:
         verbosity: 1
         election:
            verbosity: 1
         heartbeats:
            verbosity: 1
         initialSync:
            verbosity: 1
         rollback:
            verbosity: 1
      storage:
         verbosity: 1
         journal:
            verbosity: 1
         recovery:
            verbosity: 1
      write:
         verbosity: 1
```

And one more question, Do logs make any impact on mongoDb performance?
e.g. If my mongoDb logs file will goes upto 30GB of size in a day, will it impact on mongodb performance?

Answer (score 2):

Default level is `0`, i.e. level `1` will even increase the amount of logs. Remove everything below `component` to use default logging and increase it only the for the component where you like to get more detailed logs.

First, you may check which component creates the most logs.

```
for component in ACCESS COMMAND CONTROL ELECTION FTDC GEO INDEX INITSYNC JOURNAL NETWORK QUERY RECOVERY REPL REPL_HB ROLLBACK SHARDING STORAGE TXN WRITE - ; do
   c=$( jq -rcM 'select(.c == "'$component'")' /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log | wc -l )
   echo "$component => $c"
done
```

I reduced the size of logfiles significantly by setting [`operationProfiling.slowOpThresholdMs`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-operationProfiling.slowOpThresholdMs) to a higher value. Default threshold for "slow operation" is 100 Milliseconds which is fairly low I would say.